# Why my workstation PC is rendering too slow on Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2019?

Tags: video-editor, editing, adobe-media-encoder, animation-rendering, rendering

I'm wondering why my desktop workstation render too slow the video on Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2019.

I tried to edit (cut, music, simple graphics) video of 15 minutes.
But when it renders, it takes more than 1 hour.

Here is my specs:

1. I7-8700k 3.7 GHz
2. Ram 16 GB ddr4 2133
3. Samsung ssd m2 nvme 256 GB
4. Kingston 120 GB SSD
5. Toshiba 1 TB
6. Motherboard : MSI z370 gaming m5
7. Watercooling thermatalk

The only thing  I doubt in is, I do not have a graphic card as I know it's not very important in video editing and 2D as a CPU.

Please give me a solution, or where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Adobe's [system requirements for Premiere Pro](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements/2019.html)? I think you'll find that a GPU is absolutely crucial for Premiere renders. Looking at your specs you seem to have got everything fairly well specced up except for the *one thing* that will massively decrease your render times for PP.

TL;DR: get the best GPU you can afford.

Comment: Well after a week of research, you are right, thanks brother